# Angularjs - Filter does not filter one column but filters others

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have never used filters extensively in angularjs and I just saw a problem with one of my projects..

The filter that I apply to a table is filtering all columns except for the one that multiplies the values of two items in the repeater.

**1. Is this meant to work this way?**

**2. Is there a way to filter the column that multiplies numbers or adds strings together?**

Here is the plunker with a working (not working) example
http://plnkr.co/edit/pmCjQL39BWWowIAgj9hP?p=preview

I have a filter that I apply to ng-repeater...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="tableSearch">
```

And then in table..

```
<tr ng-repeat="items in tableData | filter:tableSearch">
<td> {{ items.qty }} </td>
<td> {{ items.price }} </td>

// hm.....
<td> {{ items.qty*items.price }} </td>

</tr>
```

---

### Update

Thanks to guidance from @Chandermani below I resolved the issue writing a custom filter. Here is the updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pmCjQL39BWWowIAgj9hP?p=preview

```
    $scope.tableFilter = function(item) {
        for (key in item) {
            var m = item[key].toString();
            var s = (item.qty * item.price).toString();
            if( 
                s.indexOf($scope.tableSearch) != -1 ||
                m.indexOf($scope.tableSearch) != -1 ||
                $scope.tableSearch == undefined
            ){
                return true;
            };
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then filter is used like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="items in tableData | filter:tableFilter">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter work on model data, in your case this data

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apples",
        "price": 19.99,
        "qty": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Oranges",
        "price": 29.99,
        "qty": 1
    },
```

The last column has been generated in html. You would have to write a custom filter function for supporting that or add the last column value also to your model.

For custom filter function you can do something like

```
$scope.tableFilter=function(item) {
    //should return true for the item to show up.
}
```

see documentation for filter http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Oh I see. Do you happen to have any examples of how I could approach that custom filter? By the way, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I updated my plunker with something to the tune of what you suggest but I can't get the correct result http://plnkr.co/edit/pmCjQL39BWWowIAgj9hP?p=preview If you are able to look at it, great,, if not thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: It is not working because both filters are conflicting with each other.

Comment: Thank you :) You got me on the right path. I solved it.